# Google ChromeOS > version 18 and captureVisibleTab()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I am using `captureVisibleTab` as detailed here http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(undefined,{format:"png"}, function(dataUrl){
    //checking for dataUrl here
});
```

I have wrapped the code into a QUnit test and on ChromeOS 18 I get:

[image]

So everything is working fine.

The same code run on ChromeOS 19 (beta) or 20 (dev) returns:

[image]

dataUrl is undefined

I also get a message in the Inspector saying:

> Internal Error whilst trying to capture the visible region of the
>   current tab

Incidentally, I also tried to test this on Chrome Canary (currently on version 20) and received no such issue

It seems like the api has changed, but I cant see any details of these changes in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the explanation: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=126327&q=captureVisibleTab&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

I guess/hope we will have a fix soon.